# How to remove div if its text is identical to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a d3 area chart with a tooltip that displays the same text in two different divs. The first div, `.tooltip.headline.record`, displays the selected value in bold. Another div class, `.record-label`, displays the all of the values at a given point on the x-axis — for both the selected and non-selected paths. Here's a [Plunker of the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/NfMeTpXzXGTxgNFKPFJe?p=preview).

To illustrate, it currently looks like this:[image]

I've been trying to achieve a result like this: [image]

... or like this: [image]

I've tried the following methods of hiding or removing the duplicative `.record-label` div, without success — and without error messages to assist in further diagnosis.

```
function getRecordContent(obj, pos) {
  if ( $(".tooltip-headline-record").text() == $(".record-label").text() ) {
  $(".record-label").hide();
  //$(".record-label").remove();
  //console.log("same");
  }
    return '<li><div class="record-label">' + obj.state + " " + obj.record.toLowerCase() + " " + numFormat(obj.values[pos].y) + '</div></li>'   
}
```

Here, again, is a Plunker that demonstrates the problem I'm trying to solve (see, specifically, the code beginning at line 480:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NfMeTpXzXGTxgNFKPFJe?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ab8VA92lk48rnqCJbsET?p=preview)

Relevant code changes:

1. The whole dataset was being passed to the `getRecordContent` function. So I changed that: when hovered over "**admissions**", pass "**transfers**" and "**codependents**". (line: 435)

   ```
   var filtered_dataset = dataset.filter(function(row){return row.record !== d.record; });
   for (var i = 0; i < filtered_dataset.length; i++) {
      content += getRecordContent(filtered_dataset[i], idx); 
   }
   ```
2. Seems like you need to specify the state name as well along with the record. (line 480)

   ```
   return '<li><span class="record-label">' + obj.state + ' ' + obj.record.toLowerCase() + '</span><span class="record-value">' + numFormat(obj.values[pos].y) + '</span></li>'
   ```

**Edit:**

1. Changes made for the tooltip to adapt to the main chart as well:

   ```
   var filtered_dataset = dataset.filter(function(row){return row.record !== d.record && row.state === d.state; });
   ```
2. Changed z-index for the tooltip in main.css (try removing it and hovering close to the jquery slider)

   ```
   z-index: 2;
   ```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: That's amazing; thank you! I thought it would probably be better to filter out the duplicate at a higher level, but didn't know how.

Comment: Is there a similarly simple way of hiding or filtering out `record-list` from the tooltip completely when hovering over `main-chart`, but retain `record-list` in the tooltip when mousing over the small multiples for individual states?

Comment: I had this question in my mind on how you were planning on handling the tooltips on the main chart? Cause' that didn't look right to me. Anyway, I've updated the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ab8VA92lk48rnqCJbsET?p=preview) fixing the tooltips on the main chart as well. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: My plan for main chart's tooltip is actually to display — instead of the selected state's corresponding non-selected values — (1) the total number of records (admissions, transfers, and codependents) from that state in that month, and (2) the total number of records from all states in that month. (You may have noticed the `monthTotals` and `global` array code I've been tinkering with). This, though, probably deserves to be a separate question — one which I'm working on in another window

Comment: Alright. I would like you to try it (if you don't mind) and if you face any issues, let me know and I'll help you with that. Just make sure you have a console log statement somewhere around line 435, inspect "d", "dataset", "filtered_dataset" and "content", make use of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [d3-sum](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_sum). :)

Comment: I'll throw everything I've got at it. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem. My pleasure. Keep me posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160478/discussion-between-laissezpasser-and-shashank).